# Line break In kendoUI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

In the below code I am not able to put a line break between the filds. All the field values are getting printed in the same row. Any suggestions of help would be appreciated.

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup]="editForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="CabinetName" class="control-label">Cabinet Name</label>

                    <input type="text" class="k-textbox" formControlName="CabinetName" />

                    <div class="k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation" [hidden]="editForm.controls.CabinetName.valid || editForm.controls.CabinetName.pristine">
                        CabinetName is required
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Id" class="control-label">Id</label>

                    <input type="text" class="k-textbox" formControlName="Id" />
                </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Where the row is sitting?

Comment: @RomanC the ouput which I am getting .. all the values are getting printed in a single row. I want the values to be printed in multiple rows .. Like I should get cabinetname in first row and ID in the second row

Comment: Can you remove classes from input boxes?

Comment: Even After removing the classes from input boxes I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @RomanC is there anything using which I can keep a line break point after each input boxes